# Combine two array that have some value, crash in browser

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

i have the function that combine arrays if the array have some value.
Here is my arrays :

```
var emailAddr = [{
    customerID : "C20061102105257_678",
    emails : ["fandi@gmail.com", "fanjavaid@gmail.com"]
}];

var dataEmail2 = {
    customerID : "C20061102105257_678",
    emails : ["weisk@gmail.com"]
};

var dataEmail3 = {
    customerID : "C20061102105257_600",
    emails : ["eko@gmail.com"]
};

var dataEmail4 = {
    customerID : "C20061102105257_678",
    emails : ["1@gmail.com", "156@gmail.com"]
};
```

And here is my function :

```
function addEmail(emailAddresses) {
    if(emailAddr.length == 0) {
        emailAddr.push(emailAddresses);
    } else {
        // Checking
        for (var i = 0; i < emailAddr.length; i++) {            
            if (emailAddr[i].customerID == emailAddresses.customerID) {
                for (var a = 0; a < emailAddresses.emails.length; a++) {
                    emailAddr[i]['emails'].push(emailAddresses.emails[a]);
                }

            } else {
                emailAddr.push(emailAddresses);
            }
        }

    }
} // End function

addEmail(dataEmail2);
addEmail(dataEmail3);
addEmail(dataEmail4);

console.log(emailAddr);
```

But i get crash on my browser, when execute the else statement in :

```
emailAddr.push(emailAddresses);
```

How to handle that??
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems here.

1 - You have an infinite loop by adding to an array that you are currently reading. This will cause it to expand, and you will keep reading this expansion repeatedly.

2 - You are not actually pushing NEW objects into your array, you are just simply adding a reference to existing objects. What will happen here is that when you add to your object, you are also adding to the object that you just added. In other words, you have another infinite loop here

```
for (var a = 0; a < emailAddresses.emails.length; a++) {
    emailAddr[i]['emails'].push(emailAddresses.emails[a]);
}
```

in that when you push to your array, you are actually pushing to the reference, meaning it will also expand indefintely. To fix this, use .slice(0) to copy arrays over instead, as below.

```
 var emailAddr = [{
        customerID: "C20061102105257_678",
        emails: ["fandi@gmail.com", "fanjavaid@gmail.com"]
    }];

    var dataEmail2 = {
        customerID: "C20061102105257_678",
        emails: ["weisk@gmail.com"]
    };

    var dataEmail3 = {
        customerID: "C20061102105257_600",
        emails: ["eko@gmail.com"]
    };

    var dataEmail4 = {
        customerID: "C20061102105257_678",
        emails: ["1@gmail.com", "156@gmail.com"]
    };

    function addEmail(emailAddresses) {
        if (emailAddr.length == 0) {
            emailAddr.push({ customerID: emailAddresses.customerID, emails: emailAddresses.emails.slice(0) });
        } else {
            // Checking
            var success = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < emailAddr.length; i++) {
                if (emailAddr[i].customerID == emailAddresses.customerID) {
                    success = true;
                    for (var a = 0; a < emailAddresses.emails.length; a++) {
                        console.log("adding : " + emailAddresses.emails[a]);
                        emailAddr[i]['emails'].push(emailAddresses.emails[a]);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!success) {
                emailAddr.push({ customerID: emailAddresses.customerID, emails: emailAddresses.emails.slice(0) });
            }
        }
    } // End function

    addEmail(dataEmail2);
    addEmail(dataEmail3);
    addEmail(dataEmail4);

    console.log(emailAddr);
```

Comment: for (var a = 0; a < emailsLength; a++) {
     emailAddr[a]['emails'].push(emailAddresses.emails[a]);
                }

Comment: Works :D with clean explanation. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

This might work. I guess you are trying to have an unique array of customerID's with all emails in it.

```js
function addEmail(emailAddresses) {
    if(emailAddr.length == 0) {
        emailAddr.push(emailAddresses);
    } else {
        // Checking
        var tempCheck = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < emailAddr.length; i++) {            
            if (emailAddr[i].customerID == emailAddresses.customerID) {
                for (var a = 0; a < emailAddresses.emails.length; a++) {
                    emailAddr[i]['emails'].push(emailAddresses.emails[a]);
                }
                tempCheck = false;

            } 
        }
        if(tempCheck)
        {          
            emailAddr.push(emailAddresses);
        }

    }
} // End function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function addEmail(emailAddresses) {
    if(emailAddr.length == 0) {
        emailAddr.push(emailAddresses);
    } else {
        // Checking
        for (var i = 0; i < emailAddr.length; i++) {            
            if (emailAddr[i].customerID == emailAddresses.customerID) {
                for (var a = 0; a < emailAddresses.emails.length; a++) {
                   // emailAddr[a]['emails'].push(emailAddresses.emails[a]);

                   //replaced i with a on above line
                   //replaced i with a on above line

                    emailAddr[a]['emails'].push(emailAddresses.emails[a]);

                }

            } else {
                emailAddr.push(emailAddresses);
            }
        }

    }
} // End function

addEmail(dataEmail2);
addEmail(dataEmail3);
addEmail(dataEmail4);

console.log(emailAddr);
```